# Crash after unwind segue due to location manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I have several viewcontrollers which unwind to the root viewcontroller. With most of the viewcontrollers the unwind segue works well without crashing the app. Only the viewcontrollers using a CLlocationmanager cannot perform the unwind segue to the root viewcontroller. These are the lines which makes the difference in my code:

```
//Init the location Manager
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

By commenting this section of my code the unwind works. Especially the last line makes the difference. I tried to release the locationmanager before unwinding. Sometimes it works. Somtimes it doesn`t. The debug console says:

```
0x10bfe1005:  movq   (%rdi), %r11
0x10bfe1008:  movq   %rsi, %r10
0x10bfe100b:  andl   0x18(%r11), %r10d<---Thread 1: EXC Bad_Access(code=1, adress=0x18)
0x10bfe100f:  shlq   $0x4, %r10
0x10bfe1013:  addq   0x10(%r11), %r10
```

Whatever that means. I have no idea what to do.

**EDIT**

After adding this

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager release];
}
```

it kind of works. I tried it like 5 times. Then it crashed again :( Really strange. Not sure but the error message seems to have changed. It says "WebThread" (seen below). I do have a webview which also has delegate methods. I´ll try to release the webview as well.

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x32f9af60:  cbz    r0, 0x32f9af9e            ; objc_msgSend + 62
0x32f9af62:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
0x32f9af66:  ldrh.w r12, [r9, #12]  <-----WebThread(10):EXC_bad_access(code=1, address=0x100000c)
0x32f9af6a:  ldr.w  r9, [r9, #8]
0x32f9af6e:  and.w  r12, r12, r1
0x32f9af72:  add.w  r9, r9, r12, lsl #3

0x32f9af76:  ldr.w  r12, [r9]
0x32f9af7a:  teq.w  r12, r1
0x32f9af7e:  bne    0x32f9af86                ; objc_msgSend + 38
0x32f9af80:  ldr.w  r12, [r9, #4]
0x32f9af84:  bx     r12
0x32f9af86:  cmp.w  r12, #0x1
0x32f9af8a:  blo    0x32f9af98                ; objc_msgSend + 56
0x32f9af8c:  it     eq
0x32f9af8e:  ldreq.w r9, [r9, #4]
0x32f9af92:  ldr    r12, [r9, #8]!
0x32f9af96:  b      0x32f9af7a                ; objc_msgSend + 26
0x32f9af98:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
0x32f9af9c:  b      0x32f9b1e0                ; _objc_msgSend_uncached
0x32f9af9e:  mov.w  r1, #0x0
0x32f9afa2:  bx     lr
0x32f9afa4:  nop    
0x32f9afa6:  nop    
0x32f9afa8:  nop    
0x32f9afaa:  nop    
0x32f9afac:  nop    
0x32f9afae:  nop    
0x32f9afb0:  nop    
0x32f9afb2:  nop    
0x32f9afb4:  nop    
0x32f9afb6:  nop    
0x32f9afb8:  nop    
0x32f9afba:  nop    
0x32f9afbc:  nop    
0x32f9afbe:  nop
```

**EDIT2**

Ok, after releasing the location manager and the webview in the prepareforsegue method it works.

Comment: Have you tried setting the delegate to nil. `locationManager.delegate = nil;`?

Comment: You need to add an exception breakpoint to find where in your code it is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the location manager before you unwind.

When you are unwinding you are essentially unloading and releasing the ViewController that you are unwinding from.

But, because it is the locationManager's delegate the location manager is trying to pass info to it.

You should be able to fix this with...

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

before you unwind. (Possibly in the prepareForSegue method).

Comment: nope. doesn´t work :( I put stopupdatinglocation and release of the location manager in prepareforsegue. Still crashing.

Comment: @tyler hmm :( can you add an exception breakpoint to the project and show where it's crashing. Also, show the rest of the stack trace.